# How to select content from two different tables in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, select

How can I select the contents of two columns that reside in different tables in a mysql database?

Answer (score 4):

You would need to use either a JOIN or UNION/UNION ALL.

This will depend on wht you require.

Lets say you want all values from *table 1 col a* and *table 2 col b* in seperate rows

You can use

```
SELECT ColA
FROM TABLE1
UNION ALL
SELECT ColB
FROM TABLE2
```

All Distinct Values

```
SELECT ColA
FROM TABLE1
UNION
SELECT ColB
FROM TABLE2
```

And lets say that the you want to display them in the same row, they should have some key that links them

```
SELECT ColA, ColB
FROM TABLE1 t1 INNER JOIN
   TABLE2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

It would also be good to note that there are different types of [Sql Joins](http://w3schools.com/SQL/sql_join.asp)

**Different SQL JOINs**

- JOIN: Return rows when there is at
  least one match in both tables
- LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the
  left table, even if there are no
  matches in the right table
- RIGHT JOIN: Return all rows from the
  right table, even if there are no
  matches in the left table
- FULL JOIN: Return rows when there is
  a match in one of the tables

Answer (score 0):

Use a JOIN.

http://w3schools.com/SQL/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fields
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b
ON (a.id = b.foo_id)
```